# how to clear all ouput contents that is shown to the user

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm building an app in which the user gets a response for each button press
and the response is an output which is shown to the user

This is what I do in this app:

- I have 6 different slots like for eg:  _ _ _ _ _ _  this is how it appears in the beginning
- when the user presses a button I need to give the response as:  o/P _ _ _ _ _
- this is how the user gets responses on each press: o/P o/P _ _ _ _ this continues serially until all the 6 blank spaces are filled
- finally, when the blank spaces get filled after 6 entries I want to clear all those 'o/Ps'

How can I do this operation in reactnative

Comment: I started with state but i also need to clear the state after 6 o/ps so i got stuck in it

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing your responses in your `state`, you can create an `INITIAL_STATE` const and set your state to this value after you fill your entries

Comment: I can fill it but what about removing the entries after the fields get filled

Comment: how can i remove the entries

Comment: have you tried to `setState({ ...INITIAL_STATE })`?